# how to change value into character in dataframe

Tags: r

I would like the letters "AB" to appear in place of 0, " AA" in the place of 1, and BB in place of -1.

```
SNP <- data.frame(SNP = c(-1,0,1,-1,1,1,0,-1), SNP1 = c(-1,-1,-1,1,-1,0,1,-1), SNP2 = c(0,0,0,1,-1,-1,-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
SNP %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~ case_when(. == -1 ~ "BB",
                            . == 0 ~ "AB",
                            . == 1 ~ "AA")))
```

Output:

```
  SNP SNP1 SNP2
1  BB   BB   AB
2  AB   BB   AB
3  AA   BB   AB
4  BB   AA   AA
5  AA   BB   BB
6  AA   AB   BB
7  AB   AA   BB
8  BB   BB   AA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using match

```
tmp=c(0,1,-1)
names(tmp)=c("AB","AA","BB")
sapply(SNP,function(x) names(tmp)[match(x,tmp)])

     SNP  SNP1 SNP2
[1,] "BB" "BB" "AB"
[2,] "AB" "BB" "AB"
[3,] "AA" "BB" "AB"
[4,] "BB" "AA" "AA"
[5,] "AA" "BB" "BB"
[6,] "AA" "AB" "BB"
[7,] "AB" "AA" "BB"
[8,] "BB" "BB" "AA"
```